# Could you let me know the nuance of preposition after 'say'?

Tags: prepositions

When I saw the following sentence,
 
I started to wonder about the nuance of a preposition after say verb.

> I'm saying off to misogyny.

What does it mean about say off?
and Could you let me know another case of 'say + preposition'?

Comment: Wow.  I don't think I've ever read or heard “say off”.

Comment: Do you? How unfamiliar it is to me! But your comment also help me to feel the nuance from the sentence. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"Off" is the only such preposition, as far as I know. The meaning of "saying off" something makes sense once you know it - it means **to say no to or refuse**. "Swearing off" is a similar-looking idiom identical in meaning. (I would argue that "swearing off" is more emphatic, though.)

Example of "saying off" in action:

> After the jackhammer in his head had subsided somewhat, Jack decided that he was **saying off** alcohol for a long, long time.

Edit: I just remembered another preposition that can be used with "say"! It's fairly archaic I think, or at least it's not common. Anyway, the phrase is **say on**. What does it mean? It is a command, an invitation, or a request made by the speaker to the listener to continue talking.

> David held his breath and watched Michael's face for any sign of anger at the news, but there was none. Only bland attention. "**Say on**", his friend urged.

As you can see, it sounds a bit stilted, a little contrived. However, save for a few contexts (medieval fantasy literature come to mind, like LOTR), it's going to sound that way no matter what.

Comment: Say after me, “It’s English, There’s always another one.”

Comment: Such a good expertise answer!
I appreciate your reply.

Comment: @libliboom You're very welcome! I enjoy questions like these.

Comment: It would be nice if you could supply a citation from a reputable source to support this answer. I cannot find any.

Comment: @Cascabel You're kidding, right? "Saying off" is well-known slang, and "say on" was something I got out of a random book years ago and that I've only remembered because, well, I remember stuff like that.

Comment: Well gee, if you remember stuff like that, maybe you can find some supporting documentation. Not even Urban has it.